# Closing a program which uses scheduleWithFixedDelay

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm working on a desktop application which does the same process again and again... in other words, It runs again and again all day long.

I accomplish this task using `scheduleWithFixedDelay` as bellow.

```
 private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

final ScheduledFuture<?> threadHandle = scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(mainThread, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Whenever someone clicks the close button, I want to close the program only if the task for a particulate round is finished or if it's ideal.

I done this using 2 `boolean` variables (one to check whther the user has clicked the close button and other one the check wther the process is running.)
But this method was not efficient.

Is there any efficient way to get this task done, like using build in functions.

Thanks In Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before exiting your application execute `scheduler.shutdown()` followed by `scheduler.awaitTermination(...timeout...)` ([read more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)). Later method will do what you want: if no task is running, it will return immediately, and if task is in process, it will block until task if finished (or timeout is expired).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much **Aivean** for your support..  It worked perfectly :) 
I believe this is what you suggested.

```
Thread close = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                scheduler.shutdown();
                if (!scheduler.awaitTermination(60000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                    System.err.println("Threads didn't finish in 60000 seconds!");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }

            System.out.println("Application closed..");

            System.exit(0);

        }
    });

    close.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
threadHandle.cancel(true/false);
```

Set to true will interrupt this task immediately, and set to false will wait for to be finished before closing it.